# Which driver should I use for my RX 560 for gaming?

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, fglrx, 17.10, amdgpu

I just installed 17.10 on my machine with a X4 950 (A320 chipset) and RX 560. According to the "additional drivers" tab none are in use and the only available option pertains to AMD CPUs, not GPUs. How do I get best performance?

Comment: Tree question here: 1. which driver to use?, 2. how do I get best performance?, and 3. how to stop the fan from spinning?. Way too broad, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by numerous recent benchmarks on [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-1730-radeonsi&num=1), the open-source RadeonSI driver that comes preinstalled will serve you best for OpenGL workloads (i.e. most games and software like Blender and Krita). If you require Vulkan (a new API used by certain recent Linux games) support, you can install the `mesa-vulkan-drivers` package. The only currently lacking feature in the open-source drivers compared to Catalyst/AMDGPU-PRO is OpenCL compute API support and HDMI/DisplayPort audio, both of which should be available within a year.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that on the desktop my GPU fan is spinning which it didn't do in Windows. I'm guessing the driver doesn't support that?

Comment: Sometimes you can control fan speed with the lm-sensors package. I'm not sure it would work for a GPU but it might. Unfortunately there is no GUI for this. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control